# Foursquare API venue/add uses validation for the wrong country

Tags: api, foursquare

I am trying to add a german venue about 300m close to the swiss border with these params

```
{"zip":"79576",
"v":"20130620",
"phone":"07621 706388",
"ll":"47.591834,7.635268",
"address":"Hinterdorfstr. 24"}
```

And I get the error:

```
{"field":"zip","error":"Invalid postal code format"},
{"field":"phone","error":"Invalid phone number"}
```

According to googlemaps and openstreetmap the lat/lng is in Germany. Foursquare seems to interpret it as a swiss venue and therefore validation on the zip and phone fails. 
Is there a way to explicitly set the country for the validation?